# How to replace a value by another within a variable in R?

Tags: r

mydata:

```
ID color price
1   red   120
2   red   NA 
3   blue  80 
4   green 97 
5   black 100
```

I need to replace "black" by "red" in color variable, and
replace NA by the average of price

I have tried the following codes
mydata$color[(mydata$color=="black")]<- "red" # but I get NULL instead

and for the second issue, I used
mydata$price[which(is.na(mydata$price))]<- mean(mydata$price) # but it doesn't change anything!

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What have you tried? What is the point you are struggeling with? Right now now your question is a bit too vague.

Comment: How much experience do you have using R? I think you may benefit from reading some of the documentation listed on [**this page**](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info) to better get to grips with some of the fundamentals of R. Especially check the ***Free resources*** section.

Comment: You already posted the exact same question today...

Comment: Yeah juba, sorry for that I am new in stackoverflow, and I didn't get it first!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this approach to get what you need:

```
df = within(df, {
   variable[variable == "string"] = "string2"
   variable[is.na(variable)] = mean(variable)
 })
```

The trick here is that you can create a subset using `[]` and assign values again to that subset using `[] =`.

Comment: what `=`, is see no `=`, only `==` :)

Comment: @PaulHiemstra Hi, I was wondering don't you have to use `na.rm=T` inside `mean(variable)` ?